# how to test memory usage in a symfony webtestcase

Tags: symfony, webtest

I would simply like to trace the whole amount of memory used for a request I test by means of a `WebTestCase`'s method. 
Something like this inside a `WebTestCase::testReturnValidUser` method:

```
$client = static::createClient();
        $client->enableProfiler();
        $crawler = $client->request(
            'GET',
            $userURL
        );

...

if ($profile = $client->getProfile()) {
    $this->assertLessThan(10, $profile->getSomethingForMemoryConsumption())
}
```

Sidenote: unfortunately I can't install `xhproof`. Brew seems not to give xhproof for its own php7, which I installed.

Answer (score 2):

Ok I found it: I can simply use the already existent [MemoryDataCollector](http://api.symfony.com/2.3/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/DataCollector/MemoryDataCollector.html) without defining my own `DataCollector`:

```
    if ($profile = $client->getProfile()) {
        $this->assertLessThan(30000000, $profile->getCollector('memory')->getMemory());
    }
```